# jar-size too big. How to decrease jar-size in maven-project?

Tags: java, maven, build, size, deeplearning4j

When I build my maven Project I get a big jar of 300mb. It has to be under
75mb. Is there a way to not compile unused maven libraries/dependencies?
Or is there a way to find out which libraries/dependencies my project doesnt need?

Comment: Provide the code snippet of pom.xml

Comment: A single jar file which is about 300MiB ? How many classes do you have in that module? Are you creating a executable jar?

Answer (score 1):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html is the plugin you are looking for. It will find used+undeclared (=transitive) dependencies and unused+declared dependencies.
Just be aware that it cannot detect reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to include Skinny WAR option. Could you try the following POM in your project and let us know if that helped to reduce from 300MB to?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${war-plugin-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/web.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```